# My winform application doesn't work on others' pc without vs 2010 installed

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, com

Just like I said, my winform application works properly on computers with VS installed, but on other computers, it will crash due to a `FileNotFound Exception`. I used

`using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;`

in my source code to generate a Excel file, and the problem occurs as soon as the Excel-related function is called. But I don't know what it refers to exactly. Do I have to get some `.dll` included along with the .exe file? And what `DLL` is that?

Below are part of my codes:

```
  private void FileExport(object objTable)
    {
        StartWaiting();
        string[,] table = null;
        try
        {
            table = (string[,])objTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowStatus(ex.Message, StatusType.Warning);
        }
        if (table == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Application excelApp = new Application
        {
            DisplayAlerts = false
        };
        Workbooks workbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
        Workbook workbook = workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
        worksheet.Name = "TABLE";
        for (int i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = table[i, j];
            }
        }
        Range range = excelApp.Range["A1", "H1"];
        range.Merge();
        range.Font.Bold = true;
        range.Font.Size = 15;
        range.RowHeight = 50;
        range.EntireRow.AutoFit();
        range = excelApp.Range["A2", "H8"];
        range.Font.Size = 11;
        range = excelApp.Range["A1", "H8"];
        range.NumberFormatLocal = "@";
        range.RowHeight = 300;
        range.ColumnWidth = 50;
        range.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        range.VerticalAlignment = XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
        range.EntireRow.AutoFit();
        range.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
        worksheet.UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = 1;
        Invoke(new MainThreadInvokerDelegate(SaveAs), new object[] { worksheet, workbook, excelApp }
            );
        EndWaiting();
    }
```

`

Comment: what is the exception? I think it will be helpful if you could post the stack trace

Comment: I am not sure if its related to VS not being installed. It should be mostly 'cos of the right excel version not being in the gac

Comment: I think you are missing some Dll(s), try this one : microsoft.office.interop.excel.dll

Comment: Always include error message and details.

Comment: Your users probably don't have Excel installed on their machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, you probably forgot to deploy `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` along with you application files. You could either include these files when you deploy your application or use a Windows Installer that can do this automatically for your. An installer would take care of deploying your project files and all their dependencies. On this subject [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx) says:

> The resulting Windows Installer (.msi) file contains the application,
>   any dependent files, information about the application such as
>   registry entries, and instructions for installation.

On a side note: you have to ensure Excel is installed on the other machine otherwise your application won't behave the way you expect it to do.

Comment: You mean that my users have to install Excel anyway even if I have deployed the DLL along with the application?

Comment: @wings Yes, excel needs to be present on the machine :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your program is looking for a copy of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` and is not finding it.

For this,go to Solution Explorer, make sure "Show All Files" is selected, then open your list of references.

Select your reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dl`l and press F4 to open the Properties menu. There, change Copy Local to `True`, and the referenced dll should now be copied to your output directory, meaning the file will be found and the program should work.

Comment: Note: that still requires Excel to be installed on the user's system.